# Search text in memo

Tags: delphi

I want to search for only `'2'` inside a `TMemo`'s lines. My code returns 4 results, but there should be only 1 result.

[image]

How can I prevent counting the other lines which contain `'2'`? Where am I going wrong?

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  f: Integer;
begin
  for f := 0 to Memo2.Lines.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if AnsiContainsStr(Memo2.Lines[f], Panel49.Caption) then
    begin
      Panel50.Caption := IntToStr(StrToInt(Panel50.Caption) + 1);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Use a regex and ask to search entire words only

Comment: And you really should not be updating the GUI inside the loop.

Comment: `Panel50.Caption` is not the right place to hold a variable. Use an actual variable of type integer to count things.

Comment: The name of `AnsiContainsStr()` is to be taken literally: finding texts to be contained in others. However, if you want a whole text/line to be equal to what you search for then simply **compare** it, i.e. `if memo2.lines[f] = panel49.Caption then`. Which should be obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are performing a substring search of each line.  If any line *contains* the substring, you consider it a match.  But that is not what you say you want, so you should be comparing the *entire line as a whole* instead, eg change this statement:

`if AnsiContainsStr(Memo2.Lines[f], Panel49.Caption) then`

To this instead:

`if Memo2.Lines[f] = Panel49.Caption then`

Comment: I cannot see check sign to accept as answer